# Evaluating $\int _0^{2\pi} (a\,\cos\,x+b\,\sin x)^m\,dx$ using the residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm trying to evaulate the following integral, **using complex functions**:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} (a\,\cos x+b\,\sin x)^m\,dx , \; m\in \Bbb Z$$

The hint I was given is to use a curve of the form $\{ |z|=1\}$ and the function: $$R\biggl(\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(z+ \frac{1}{z}\Bigr),\frac{1}{2i}\Bigl(z-\frac{1}{z}\Bigr)\biggr)$$

(here $R(x,y)$ denotes a rational function of $x,y$).

I tried to subtitute $z=\cos(t)+i\,\sin(t)$, and to use the residue theorem, but I had a hard time calculating the residue. Any ideas how to continue?

**Edit**:
My calculations: after plugging $z=\cos(t)+i\,\sin(t)$, I got:

$$\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1}\bigg(\frac{a}{2}\bigg(z+\frac{1}{z}\bigg)+\frac{b}{2i}\bigg(z-\frac{1}{z}\bigg)\bigg)^m\frac{dz}{z} =\dots=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(z^2(a-ib)+a+ib)^m}{2^m \cdot iz^{m+1}}dz$$

I got a pole of order $m+1$, and I got stuck calculating the residue.

Comment: Write $\cos(x)=(z+1/z)/2$, where $z=\exp(ix)$, and similarly for $\sin(x)$, to end up with an integral in terms of $z$.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried, and it lead nowhere.

Comment: Can you write down the integral you get in terms of $z$? You should get something of the form $f(z)/z^k$, where $f(z)$ is analytic for $|z|\leq 1$, after which you can apply Cauchy's Integral Formula (or residue theorem).

Comment: I think $m\geq 0$ otherwise you would have singularities, right?

Comment: The $f$ I got was something in the power of $m$, in order to calculate the residue I had to find the $m-1$- derivative , which is a problem. I will edit to add my calculations.

Comment: @Shashi Why are singularities bad? I'm even expecting them - for that I want to use the residue theorem.

Comment: Then you have them on your integration path... The integral simply diverges, you can check that.

Comment: After you set $z=e^{ix}$, then you have a contour integral on $|z|=1$.  You fogot $i$ in the denominator of both of your integrals. Just a sanity check, if your integral on the right would be good then a straightforward calculation using the residue theorem would give you a complex number. But you have started with a real integral.....? Impossible!

Comment: @Shashi Thank you, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $m\geq 0$, otherwise the integral is divergent (verify this!). Set $z=e^{ix}$ so that $dz = iz\,dx$, hence your integral is (after some fine massaging):
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(\alpha z^2+\beta)^m}{iz^{m+1}}\,dz
\end{align}
Where $\alpha=\frac{a}{2}-i\frac{b}{2}$ and $\beta=\overline{\alpha}$. Use [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to get:
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(\alpha z^2+\beta)^m}{iz^{m+1}}\,dz=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{iz^{m+1}}\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}\alpha^kz^{2k}\beta^{m-k}\,dz
\end{align}
You can easily see that the only residue is at zero. That thing does have a power equal to $-1$ only when $2k-m-1=-1$. Only possible when $m$ is even and the that is when $k=m/2$. You can conclude that when $m$ is odd the integral is zero. So assume $m$ is even. We get by the residue theorem:
\begin{align}
\int^{2\pi}_0 \left(a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)\right)^m \,dx=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(\alpha z^2+\beta)^m}{iz^{m+1}}\,dz=2\pi  \binom{m}{m/2}\alpha^{m/2}\beta^{m/2}
\end{align}
The only thing that is left is to translate this back. Just put $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. And notice that the integral is real because $\alpha\beta=|\alpha|^2$.

---

**Edit** To see why the integral is divergent if $m\in\mathbb{Z}^-$. Assume furthermore that at least $a$ or $b$ is nonzero, otherwise how you define $0^m$?. First set $n=-m$. Let us consider only one part of the integral namely:
\begin{align}
J=\int^{\pi}_0 \left( a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)\right)^m\,dx
\end{align}
Substitute $x=2\arctan(t)$ to get rid of the sines and cosines then you can verify that we get:
\begin{align}
J&=\int^\infty_0 \left( a\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}+b\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^m\frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2}\\
&=\int^\infty_0 \left( \frac{a-at^2+2bt}{1+t^2}\right)^m\frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2}\\
&\stackrel{n=-m}{=}\int^\infty_0 \frac{2(1+t^2)^{n-1}}{(a-at^2+2bt)^n}\,dt
\end{align}
Now it is easy to see that the integral is divergent. It suffices to show that $a-at^2+2bt=0$ for some $t\in[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Great solution! but I still don't understand, why is the integral divergent for $m < 0$ ? according to an integral calculator, it is not true

Comment: On second thought, doesn't $m<0$ imply there are no singularities? and thus the integeral is zero?

Comment: @user401516 I have edited the question to see why it is divergent for $m<0$. Re your second comment: $m<0$ implies that are singularities on your contour which is very bad to have. No residue theorem can be applied..

Comment: Why is it then, for example, that $\int_0 ^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2cosx+3sinx}dx$ is zero? according to this site: https://www.integral-calculator.com/#

Comment: @user401516 that integral calculator probably calculates the Cauchy Principal Value or does not work probably. You may know that machines can make mistakes. What do you think that is wrong with the things that I have written after the EDIT section? Did you read it carefully? It is true that are things left that you should verify etc etc , but it is all calculus..

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi} (a\,\cos x+b\,\sin x)^m\,dx$$ then by defining $cos\theta_0={{a}\over{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}$ and $sin\theta_0={{b}\over{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}$ we have:
$$I=(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^m\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^m(x-\theta_0)dx=(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^m\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^mxdx$$
with substituting $z=e^{i\theta}$ and $dz=izd\theta$ we get:
$$I=({\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\over 2})^m\int_C{1\over {iz}}(z+{1\over z})^mdz=({\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\over 2})^m{1\over {i}}\int_C{{(z^2+1)^m}\over z^{m+1}}dz=$$
where $C$ is unit circle. First let m to be nonnegative. Then the residue of $\Large {{(z^2+1)^m}\over z^{m+1}}$ in $z=0$ is factor of $1\over z$ in Laurent expansion which is $\binom{m}{m\over 2}$ when $m$ is even and $0$ when it's odd. Therefore the integral becomes $\Large2\pi({\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\over 2})^m\binom{m}{m\over 2}$ at this case.
Now let $m<0$. We deduce that there are two non single poles on unit circle and therefore complex integration theory can't be applied easily and directly. At this case you need to choose an alternative way.