# $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^n\theta\,d\theta$ by integration in the complex plane

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I need help with this problem:

Use the integration in the complex plane to calculate the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^n\theta\,d\theta$$
I thought to make $z= e^{i\theta}$ and rewrite the integral like this
$$\oint_{C_1}\left (\dfrac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}\right )^n\dfrac{dz}{iz}=\dfrac{1}{i2^n}\oint_{C_1}\dfrac{(z+z^{-1})^n}{z}dz$$
Then with the integral in this form
$$\oint_{C_1}\dfrac{(z+z^{-1})^n}{(z-0)}dz$$
apply the cauchy integral formula, but isn't possible because the function $(z+z^{-1})^n$ is not defined in $0$.

What can I do?

Comment: You have to first use the binomial theorem to expand the numerator and properly analyze the order of the pole at $z=0$. After that, use the residue theorem.

Comment: You have to fully isolate the pole by forcing the numerator to be analytic without changing the whole expression. In this situation this is pretty easy to do, just multiply top and bottom by $z^n$ to get $(z^2+1)^n/z^{n+1}$. What's annoying now is that this is a pole of arbitrary order.

Comment: This is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2598748/42969.

Answer (score 2):

Since the function has a singularity at $z=0$ we just have to find the residue at $z=0$:

$$I = \frac{1}{i}\oint_{C_1}\dfrac{(\frac{z^2+1}{2z})^n}{z}dz = \frac{1}{i} \oint_{C_1}\dfrac{(z^2+1)^n}{2^nz^{n+1}}dz = 2\pi \operatorname{Res}(f,0)$$

where

$$f(z) = \dfrac{(z^2+1)^n}{2^nz^{n+1}}$$

Expand with the binomial theorem $(z^2+1)^n$:

$$(z^2+1) = \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j} z^{2j}$$

Hence

$$ I= \frac{1}{i}\oint_{C_1}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j} \dfrac{z^{2j}}{2^nz^{n+1}}dz =  \frac{1}{i}\oint_{C_1}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\frac{1}{2^n}z^{2j-n-1} dz $$

The residue is the coefficient of $\displaystyle z^{-1}=z^{2j-n-1}$

Hence $$ 2j-n-1=-1 \Longrightarrow j = \frac{n}{2}$$

If $n=2m+1, \; m\in \mathbb{N} $ then since $j$ is an integer, the residue is zero and $I=0$

if $n=2m,  \;  m\in \mathbb{N} $ then $j= m$ and the residue is

$$\operatorname{Res}(f,0)= \binom{n}{m}\frac{1}{2^{m}}$$

Hence
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\cos^n\theta\,d\theta = \begin{cases} 0 &\textrm{ if } n=2m+1\;\; m\in \mathbb{N} \\ \displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2^{m-1}} \binom{n}{m} &\textrm{ if } n=2m \;\; m\in\mathbb{N} \end{cases}$$